# Setting up models with left joined tables in PHPActiveRecord

Tags: sql, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to figure out how to model the following in PHPActiveRecord, but am getting stuck and wanted to see if someone could help me out. I'll use a simplified example:

Table List:

```
atable (id [PK], ...)
btable (id [PK], ...)
ctable (atable_id [FK], btable_id [FK], statuscode)
```

The foreign keys on ctable are a composite primary key, therefore, there is only one instance of a given atable_id and btable_id in the table.

I'd like to be able to left join `atable` with `ctable` and `btable` to get at the `statuscode` column.  So a sample SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT     a.id, b.id, c.statuscode
FROM       atable a
LEFT JOIN  ctable c on c.atable_id=a.id 
LEFT JOIN  btable b on c.btable_id=b.id
```

How would I setup my 3 models (atable, btable, ctable) to be able to get at the above information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, phpactiverecord does not support composite primary keys, so for some functionality you might want to define a seperate key anyway.

Further: the statuscolumn would not be unique in this case? There could be multiple `btable_id` entries for your `atable_id`, so there would not be a single hit on that -> this is not something that has much to do with creating the objects?

Apart from that, creating the objects shouldn't be too difficult
You'd have relations that reflect the connection between `ctable.atable_id` and `atable.id` (and as well for `btable` obviously).

one `ctable` entry (object, model) 'belongs' to an `atable` and a `btable`, so you can just define a belongs-to relation for those two.
The other way around, an `atable` row (object, model) can have multiple `ctable` rows, so define that relation as `hasmany`.

to get from an atable to the status you could then do

```
foreach ($atable->ctables as $ctable) {
    echo $ctable->btable->id.' '.$ctable->statuscode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your relationship description helped me setup the models the right way.